# Pyglet, surface not showing

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pyglet

I'm trying some stuff under PyGlet and I'm facing an issue I can't manage to solve by myself.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet import gl


win = pyglet.window.Window()


@win.event
def on_draw():
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    z = 0

    gl.glBegin(gl.GL_QUADS)

    gl.glColor3ub(0xff, 0x00, 0x00)
    gl.glVertex3d(50, 50, z)
    gl.glVertex3d(50, 100, z)
    gl.glVertex3d(100, 100, z)
    gl.glVertex3d(100, 50, z)

    gl.glEnd()


pyglet.app.run()
```

This code draws a square on the screen. But if I set z to be something else than -1, 0 or 1, the square isn't showing.

I would like to build a rotating cube, so I need this z axis.

Any help on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional OpenGL setting, the valid range for Z is any float in the range (-1.0, 1.0) only.  Your vertexes will be ignored if z coordinate is outside.